# PDO's FETCH_INTO $this class does not work

Tags: php, pdo

I want to populate class with constructor using `FETCH_INTO` of PDO:

```
class user
{
    private $db;
    private $name;

    function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->db = ...;

        $q = $this->db->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = ?");
        $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $this);
        $q->execute(array($id));

        echo $this->name;
    }
}
```

This does not work. No error, just nothing. Script has no errors, `FETCH_ASSOC` works fine.

What is wrong with `FETCH_INTO`?

Comment: I recently went through this way of defining objects, for me using PDO and the fetch method to fill objects is the most convenient I could see.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have two errors in your code:

1) You forgot $q->fetch()

```
 ...
 $q->execute(array($id));
 $q->fetch(); // This line is required
```

2) But even after adding $q->fetch() you'll get this:

> Fatal error: Cannot access private
>   property User::$name in ...

So, as you can see, PDO cannot access private members even if it is called inside class method.

Here is my solution:

```
...
$q->execute(array($id));
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data = $q->fetch();
foreach ($data as $propName => $propValue)
{
    // here you can add check if class property exists if you don't want to
    // add another properties with public visibility
    $this->{$propName} = $propValue;
}
```

Comment: You can also just make `$name` a public variable. It sure sounds like one.

Comment: +this example was super helpful

Comment: thats still throwing the same error: `Fatal error: Cannot access private property User::$name in ...`

Comment: You need to add an accessor to set the private variable.