# PHP PDO - FETCH_INTO , $this . Populating a pre-instantiated object

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to use PDO to populate a User object.

I've simplified my code slightly, (SQL etc) but essentially I have this:

```
    Class User
    {       
        protected $id;  
        protected $email;
        protected $password;

        public function tokenCheck()
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM blah LIMIT 1';

            $STH = $this->DBH->prepare($sql);
            $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $this);
            $STH->execute();

            $result = $STH->fetch();
        }

    }
```

Which I call with:

```
$User->tokenCheck();
```

When I var dump my User Object I get:

```
object(User)#1 (7) { ["id":protected]=> NULL [ ["email"]=> NULL ["password":protected]=> NULL ["token":protected]=> NULL }
```

I've tried setting all my property's to public, with the same result. All the values stay at NULL.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296092/pdos-fetch-into-this-class-does-not-working) SO answer didn't work for me either.

Comment: Try specifically selecting the columns you need with the appropriate names (and if the names don't exactly match, use aliases)

Comment: Also just a note, it shouldn't be the `User`'s responsibility to fetch information about itself. There should be a different object that would collect this data and create a `User` object with it.

Comment: Have you tried a var_dump on your $result variable to check if it isn't empty ?

Comment: damn. Yep. That was it, for some reason a hashed value wasn't selecting in the SQL. Set all my properties to public, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "User");
```

It will instantiate a User class populated with your data.

Comment: That just gives me array(0) { }

Comment: Where did you call the instantiation ? As Madara Uchiha outlined it shouldn't be the User's class responsibility to fetch data about itself.

Comment: Thanks, so where should the data be fetched from? Not the Controller, a Factory class?

Comment: Yep, I'd use a factory class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is u are trying to select the id, email and password into your User class but they are protected, you could even leave the properties out as the column names will define the property names.

```
Class User
{       
    PUBLIC $id;  
    PUBLIC $email;
    PUBLIC $password;

    public function tokenCheck()
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM blah LIMIT 1';

        $STH = $this->DBH->prepare($sql);
        $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $this);
        $STH->execute();

        $STH->fetch();
    }

}
```