# PDO fetch into existing object

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to use PDO to pull data from a database and into the current object.  Code:

```
class Voucher {

    //Database and object have EXACTLY the same fields/properties/columns

    protected $voucher_id;
    protected $voucher_code;
    protected $voucher_value;
    protected $voucher_product_type;
    protected $voucher_status;

    // still in the class declaration
    public function load_voucher($voucher_code){

        global $conn;  //load database connection info

            $stmt = $conn->prepare('select * from cart_voucher_table where voucher_code = :voucher_code');
            $stmt->execute(array('transaction_id' => $this_transaction_id));

             I HAVE NO IDEA, NO PDO statement works

            // Current object (which existed but was empty) now contains values from first row of returned data from db
     }
}
```

//usage

```
$this_voucher = new voucher();   //creates new voucher object
$this_voucher->load_voucher($voucher_code);  //loads data from database into the current voucher object.
```

I've searched for quite some time, with no result.  All of the solutions I've seen either have the function outside of the class, or they return a new object, NOT the current one.

Comment: You are mapping `transaction_id` when you execute when your statement is prepared for `voucher_code`.  Also, `$this_transaction_id` isn't defined, though I'm certain you mean to use `$this->transaction_id`

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Yup.  Fixed that.  It still doesn't work.  It fails on $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO:FETCH_CLASS, 'Voucher');  This is before the query is actually executed.  The error is: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: I've tried every variation of setting the fetch mode and executing the statement I can think of.  I believe I need a line to set the PDO mode to fetch into the current object, but I can't figure out how to set it up.

Comment: Try using `bindValue()` before executing.

Comment: Where do you call fetch() on the PDOStatement?

Comment: The fetch() is in the area I'm having trouble with.  I just want to set the fetchmode to the current class and fetch the first row into the current object.  Right now I can't figure out how to set the Fetchmode to the current object instead of a NEW instance of the class.

Comment: Can you post the code you currently have? 'Cause In the current one there are issues with the named parameter as the answer says.

Comment: `$stmt = $conn->prepare('select * from cart_voucher_table where voucher_code = :voucher_code');` 

  `$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);` 


  `$stmt->execute(array('voucher_id' => $voucher_code));` 


The code fails on the setFetchMode line, no matter what settings I use.  The fetch() doesn't matter, because it never gets there.

Comment: I think my question is more generic.  What is the correct syntax to set the PDO FetchMode in a function INSIDE a class in order to update the current object of that class type?  Or is this impossible and the function (and PDO statement) MUST be outside of the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PDO inside of a model/value object to populate the properties of the object is a *terrible* design decision.  I don't say that to knock your code, but to encourage you to use a different technique.  The pain you'll avoid in maintainability alone will be worth the effort to choose a new design.  I have a suggestion after the solution.

**SOLUTION**

This issue has been dealt with here before: "[PDO's FETCH_INTO $this class does not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3296207/1134565)".  Using that technique should take care of your issue.

**SUGGESTION**

My suggestion is to go another route entirely.  Consider creating a Voucher DAO that would look something like this:

```
class VoucherDao
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(\PDO $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function findVoucher($voucher_code)
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('select * from cart_voucher_table where voucher_code = :voucher_code');
        $stmt->bindValue(':voucher_code', $voucher_code);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Voucher');
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->fetch();
    }
}
```

Rather than creating a new voucher and then loading it, you'd use the DAO to create the voucher already filled with data.

```
$dao = new VoucherDao($conn);
$voucher = $dao->findVoucher(12345);
```

Of course, since I don't have the entire voucher code, I can't test this.  If I remember correctly, you'll need to create setters in your Voucher class to allow `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` to work properly.  Test both with and without if you give my suggestion a try.

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer addresses the problem.  I also appreciate the suggestion that I'm going about it incorrectly.  
  
I am going to create a separate class, like you displayed above.  

Is this a good design decision in general?  Should I be creating one class that contains the object and then other classes to do other things, or is this specific to loading data via PDO?

Comment: Yes, you should create classes that do very focused things. This style of separation of responsibilities is an application of the Single Responsibility Principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), a part of the SOLID principles (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).  You'll thank yourself down the road for the extra effort you put in now.

Comment: VoucherService should be named VoucherDao as it's responsible for data access (in those Dao classes I do finding, saving, updating, etc).

Answer (score 0):

"The keys from input_parameters must match the ones declared in the SQL. Before PHP 5.2.0 this was silently ignored."

From: http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.execute.php

In your MySQL, when preparing the statement, you have the named parameter ":voucher_code" but the key in the array for execution is "transaction_id" - so this might be your problem I guess, as your wrote a comment on getting the an error message concerning the parameters.

Also, I don't see $stmt->fetch() getting called anywhere in your code...?

Comment: I fixed the issue with the parameter names.

I'm not even getting to the fetch(). I'm just trying to set the fetch to fetch into the current object. 



$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, new Voucher);  

gives: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: classname must be a string.



$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Voucher");

gives: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined