# PHP PDO FETCH_INTO $this (or alternative) with protected or private properties

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to create a fetch method for a class; here is a (possibly over-) simplified example:

```
<?php
class User {
    protected $name;
    public function fetch($id) {
        global $db;
        $sql = "SELECT [name] FROM [user] WHERE [id] = :id";
        $ins = array ('id' => $id);
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $this);
        $stmt->execute($ins);
        $stmt->fetch();
    }
}
```

Now, it would be lovely if this worked, but, of course, it doesn't as `$name` is a protected property and therefore I get the error.

```
 Cannot access protected property User::$name yadda yadda....
```

So, I've spent a while scouring the Internet to try and find an alternative approach and although I've found a few suggestions which could work, I'm hoping someone might be able to recommend an approach. Obviously I don't want to make User's properties public or use a magic setter.

Comment: You could use a `stdClass` and then copy the public properties within it to your protected properties, if the fetch is successful?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3296207/612202

Comment: I have implemented the suggestion in that answer.  I don't know though; it feels a little excessive!

Comment: I agree, but as stated in the answer, PDO can't access the private members, so I don't see another way to do this.

Comment: I figured as much; seems a shame! Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score -1):

You are not using $name or $this->name anywhere in the code sample, so I assume you are trying to set the $name property from outside the object.

So why not pass that value in on the constructor method

```
<?php
class User {
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name) 
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function fetch($id) {
        global $db;
        $sql = "SELECT [name] FROM [user] WHERE [id] = :id";
        $ins = array ('id' => $id);
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $this);
        $stmt->execute($ins);
        $stmt->fetch();
    }
}
```

Then when you instantiate the class you just do it with a parameter.

```
$cUser = new User('Fred');
```

**ADDED AFTER SOME CLARIFICATION:**

PDO::FETCH_INTO: updates an existing instance of the requested class, mapping the columns of the result set to named properties in the class.

So it follow that you must have an existing instantiated object to put the data into before running the setFetchMode() and fetch() where the property names match some or all of the rows in your query result.

```
<?php
class User {
    protected $row;

    public function fetch($id) {
        global $db;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = :id";
        $ins = array ('id' => $id);
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($ins);

        // Create a class 
        $this->row = new stdClass();

        // Now creates the properties you are interested in
        $this->row->name = '';
        $this->row->dob = '';
        $this->row->email = '';

        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $this->row);
        $stmt->fetch();

        print_r($this->row);
    }

}
?>
```

I hope this is a bit more help.

Comment: No your assumption is incorrect.  My question is how to go about using PDO's FETCH_INTO $this within a class with private/protected properties

Comment: I have amended my answer now I understand the question